# Error trying to get page title in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

Can you help me with the correct `XPath` to select the text of the title "Quotes to Scrape" contained in the `<a>` tag inside an `<h1>` tag on the following [webpage](https://quotes.toscrape.com/)?

I need to use this `XPath` on the `IMPORTXML` function in Google Sheets, but I'm not sure if the `XPath` is correct.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://quotes.toscrape.com/","//div[@class='col-md-8']/h1/a")
```

I have an error in `Google Sheets`.
I am expecting to get the text inside `/h1/a`.

Comment: Looks like a typo, `=IMPORTXML("http://quotes.toscrape.com/","//div[@class='col-md-8']/h1/a")` works fine.

Comment: Please add the formula error. Besides adding value shown in the cell also add the error description shown when mouse hovering the red triangle in cell showing the error.

Comment: @Gabriele Ferrari, could you provide the error code that you are getting? I tested the formula and it is working for me. Could you update your question with a screenshot of the error or the wording?

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to use a semicolon instead of comma:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://quotes.toscrape.com/";"//div[@class='col-md-8']/h1/a")
```

Comment: The use of semicolon instead of comma as parameter separator is required because of the country setting of your spreadsheet. For coutries that use comma as decimal sepator they should use semicolon as the separator of function parameters.

Answer (score -1):

I'm writing this answer as a community wiki since the solution was provided by @[margusl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/646761/margusl) in the comments section, for visibility to the community.

The issue was related to a typo with the formula. The formula with the issue was

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://quotes.toscrape.com/","//div[@class='col-md-8']/h1/a")
```

However, `IMPORTHTML` doesn't use XPath, it uses a query like "List" or "Table" as mentioned [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339).

So to fix the issue, you need to fix the typo and use:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://quotes.toscrape.com/","//div[@class='col-md-8']/h1/a")
```

Or you can also use:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://quotes.toscrape.com/","/html/body/div/div[1]/div[1]/h1/a")
```